# Convert from EPSG:4326 to UTM in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, convert, utm

I would like to **convert from EPSG:4326 to UTM (30N/EPSG:32630 or 29N/EPSG:32629) in PostGIS**. I do the following query but I get wrong results:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(36.5277099609375 -5.86424016952515)',4326),32630)) As check;
```

I get `"POINT(5262418.33128724 -839958.963432011)"` when it should be something approximate to `243625.00,4046330.00` in UTM 30N. If I do the conversion from 4326 to UTM I get the right result but not from UTM to 4326.

- What's wrong with the query?
- And are there anyway to get the UTM timezone from the coordinates in
  EPSG:4326 because I don't know if they belong to 30N or 29N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with your data. `POINT(36.5277099609375 -5.86424016952515)` is on the southern Hemisphere at 36°E and 5° South.

I guess you rather want `POINT(-5.86424016952515 36.5277099609375)` which is close to the border of 29N and 30N.

The borders between the UTM zones are 6 degrees apart, starting from -180° in the West. But there are some exceptions around Norway.

Comment: It's that! Thanks! But I have one more issue. The X means the longitude and the Y means the latitude always? Because e.g. in Google Maps i think they are changed.

Comment: You better think of the x-axis horizontally, and the y-axis vertically. No matter if they are degrees or meters. And most GIS software expects the data in X-Y order.